# Fetching individual JSON data on reactJS

Tags: json, spring, reactjs, rest

When I parse A JSON from my server to my react front end it works fine perfectly but when I add a parameter to display an individual item I get an error. How do I display individual JSON data on react JS. I get the JSON data from my rest server. My code looks like the following.

In order to get the JSON I use the following method.

```
state = {
    isLoading: true,
    groups: [],
};  

async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch('/product/all/1');
    const body = await response.json();
    this.setState({ groups: body, isLoading: false });
}
```

This is how I call the array

```
  {this.state.groups.map(group => <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 p-b-50">
                                    {/* Block2 */}
                                    <div className="block2">
                                        <div className="block2-img wrap-pic-w of-hidden pos-relative block2-labelnew">
                                             <img src={group.thumbnail} />
                                            <div className="block2-overlay trans-0-4">
                                                <a href="#" className="block2-btn-addwishlist hov-pointer trans-0-4">
                                                    <i className="icon-wishlist icon_heart_alt" aria-hidden="true" />
                                                    <i className="icon-wishlist icon_heart dis-none" aria-hidden="true" />
                                                </a>
                                                 <button key={group.id} onClick={() => this.add(group.productid, group.name)} className="flex-c-m size1 bg4 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4">Add to Cart</button>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="block2-txt p-t-20">

                                             <a  href={`/productdetails/` + group.productid}>{group.name}</a>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>)}
```

I get an error saying "**TypeError: this.state.groups.map is not a function**"

My Spring backend to call all items and individual items look as the following

```
@GetMapping("/product")
public List<Product> index(){
    return productRepository.findAll( );
}

@GetMapping("/product/all/{id}")
public Product show(@PathVariable String id){
    int productId = Integer.parseInt(id);
    return productRepository.findOne(productId);
}
```

P.S both api's seem working fine when tested on postman and fetching ("api/products") too works fine

Comment: /product/all/{id} API will return single object (.findOne)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.state.groups.map is not a function` . This means React expects `this.state.groups` to be an array. If you are returning only one item then do it like it this:

```
this.setState({ groups: [body], isLoading: false });
```

this way, body will be the first and only item in an array.